# Как закрыть изображение модуль PIL (Pillow) python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pillow, pil

У меня открывается изображение с помощью show(), но я не знаю как его закрыть. Пробовал close() - не работает.

```
def showImage():
    im = Image.open('image.png')
    im.show()
    time.sleep(5) # Это для того чтобы картинка успела открыться перед закрытием
    im.close()
```

Comment: Там всё не так просто, но есть варианты: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6725171/8324991 Просто картинка открывается во внешнем просмотрщике и как-то надо его убивать потом

Answer (score 1):

Если не принципиально PIL, c ним тоже можно попробовать но у меня посыпались ошибки изображения. Причина в том что открытие картинки через `im.show()`блокирует следующие команды до закрытия окна, поэтому нужен свой процесс.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.image as mpimg
from multiprocessing import Process
import time

def show_img():
  img = mpimg.imread('image.png')
  # cпрятать меню
  plt.rcParams['toolbar'] = 'None'
  imgplot = plt.imshow(img)
  plt.axis('off')
  plt.show()

def timeout(fn, sec):
  p = Process(target=fn)
  p.start()
  p.join(timeout=sec)
  p.terminate()

if __name__ == '__main__':
  timeout(show_img, 5)
```

Все оказалось проще, нужно вместо `show` вызывать `pause`

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.image as mpimg

def show_img():
  img = mpimg.imread('image.png')
  plt.rcParams['toolbar'] = 'None'
  imgplot = plt.imshow(img)
  plt.axis('off')
  plt.pause(5)

showImage()
```

Comment: Я вставил код и возникла данная ошибка RuntimeError: 
        An attempt has been made to start a new process before the
        current process has finished its bootstrapping phase.

        This probably means that you are not using fork to start your
        child processes and you have forgotten to use the proper idiom
        in the main module:

            if __name__ == '__main__':
                freeze_support()
                ...

        The "freeze_support()" line can be omitted if the program
        is not going to be frozen to produce an executable.

Comment: @ТЁМА я обновил ответ, должно подойти нет процесса

Comment: @DaniilLoban С многопоточностью обязательно нужно вызов функции оборачивать в `if __name__ == '__main__'`, вне его должны быть только `import` и `def`.

Comment: @CrazyElf буду, знать, но обошлось без нее вроде

Answer (score 0):

Вот что нагуглил:

```py
import time
import psutil
from PIL import Image
import threading

im = Image.open('image.png')
def myfunc():
    print('основной поток стартовал')
    im.show()
    
def stopfunc():
    time.sleep(5)
    for proc in psutil.process_iter():
        if proc.name() == "display":
            proc.kill()
            print('основной поток закрыт')

thr1 = threading.Thread(target = myfunc).start()
thr2 = threading.Timer(5.0, stopfunc())
```

UPD:
Посмотрел доки на **pcutil**. Лучше не **proc.kill()** использовать, а **proc.terminate()**. Безопасней и не ругается.